# Generating function / combinations for a sum with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

So the general story is "we draw identical marbles (with replacement) and place them randomly in 3 different bins" (generic stars / bars), we continue drawing until a bin has exactly 10 marbles.

1. I would like to find the distribution.

I assumed that finding the total number of combinations would be easier if I partition the space by total number of marbles drawn {10,11,...,28} and then count the combinations for each. However the generic stars / bars solution doesn't apply since the restriction on each bin is `0=<Bi<=10 and least one bin has exactly 10`. I looked at various solutions involving restrictions and generatic functions but can't quite find the right one.

2. In addition to the above restrictions every time we draw a marble there is a 1/5 chance to draw 2 marbles instead and place them in one bin.
3. There is 1/10 chance to draw 3 marbles and place each in a different bin, this is in addition to #2, ie. #2 can happen, #3 can and 2 and 3 can ie. 2/100 chance to draw 6 balls and place 2 in each bin.

(Edit) Some clarifications:

A: I'm looking for the chance that we drew exactly 10,11... or 28 times for the base case, eg. there are exactly 3 ways to have drawn 10 times. So the order in which the bins are filled does matter here.

B: As to #2, #3 as I mentioned in A the order in which the bins are filled matters since I'm looking at the distribution of the various sums. The bins overflow (ie. if you have 9 and place 2 you still have 10), and yes with #3 it's possible to have 10 marbles in all 3 bins (in the base case however that would be impossible since process stops when we reach 10 in any).

I guess an alternative way to describe the base case would be we have a 3 sided die (A,B,C), we roll a die until we have either 10 A's or 10 B's or 10 C's, what is the chance to have rolled 10 times, 11 times etc.

for #2 and #3, the die would be weighted with each side representing the combinations (we get 1 A, or we get 2 B's or we get ABC etc).

Comment: (Ignoring constraints 2 and 3...) Exactly one bin has ten marbles (*$m$ in general*).  Choose which bin that is in $3$ ways (*in $k$ ways in general*).  Then, we choose how to distribute marbles among the other bins in $10^2$ ways (*in $m^{k-1}$ ways in general*).  This gives a total of $k\cdot m^{k-1}$ possible outcomes where by outcome we consider *only* the total numbers of marbles in each bin, not in which order marbles were placed.

Comment: As for if we allow constraints 2 or 3... you need to be clearer as to what exactly we are after... if you are merely wanting to *count* the number of possible outcomes, then the probabilities you are referring to are completely irrelevant.  What happens if we pass 10 marbles in a bin (e.g. by having 9 marbles in a bin originally, then two more are placed in the bin putting the total to 11)?  What happens if we reach 10 marbles in multiple bins simultaneously?  Do we even care to remember whether two marbles get placed simultaneously versus one marble placed twice in a row?

Comment: I added a few clarifications to the original question.

Comment: If you’re drawing marbles with replacement, how are they ending up in the bins?

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question, imagine a sack with infinite number of marbles we reach in and pick one (or more in the case of #2, #3) and place it in a bin.